# Mysql -optimizar consulta

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

Tenga una consulta sobre una BD MySQL donde hago un join entre una **tabla de documentos** y sus **lineas** , para ello hago esta consulta y tarda **13segundos** en ejecutar filtrando por el año 2020 , devuelve 6 millones de registros

```
SELECT a.documento, a.tipo
FROM lineas a
INNER JOIN
cabezera c ON a.documento = c.documento and a.tipo = c.tipo
WHERE
YEAR(str_to_date(c.fecha, '%d-%m-%y')) >= 2020
```

Mi idea es hacer esta consulta con un having count, para buscar aquellos documentos que tienen más de 50 registros en la tabla de lineas , para ello ejecuto esta factura

```
SELECT a.documento, a.tipo
FROM lineas a INNER JOIN
cabezera c ON a.documento = c.documento and a.tipo = c.tipo
WHERE YEAR(str_to_date(c.fecha, '%d-%m-%y')) >= 2020
GROUP BY a.documento, a.tipo
HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
ORDER BY rand()
limit 5
```

Esta consulta tarda 67segundos.

Si miro la ejecución me muestra lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Decir que en ambas tablas hay un índice de los campos documento y tipo.

Comment: Y si tiras la consulta sobre las cabeceras, y después le haces el inner join con las líneas?

Comment: hay otra comunidad sobre code review, quizás ahí te puedan ayudar mejor

Comment: Usa una VIEW (vista) y agrégale los índices a las columnas con los que trabajas los INNER JOIN y deja de usar HAVING, hasta donde tengo entendido es una mala práctica y alenta demasiado las consultas cuando no es aplicada correctamente. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439872/whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where-in-mysql-query